# What kind of SSL certificate I should buy for my web services?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, wcf, ssl

I'm new to HTTPS/SSL in web applications scenario.

I have a number of RESTful web services that are running on a particular subdomain on our website: 'f31.mycompany.com'. These web services are consumed by various ASP.NET MVC applications and some NativeScript applications. The path for the web services usually goes like 'http://f31.mycompany.com/webservicegroup1/service1.svc'.

I was asked to expose these services using HTTPS. We tried the self-signed certificate, but that experiment failed, since the web applications crashed due to trust issues of a self-signed certificate.

Now I have to purchase a SSL certificate and have narrow it down to a DV certificate. I'm confused about the following:

Do I need separate SSL certificate for each web service? All services run on the same domain 'f31.mycompany.com', however sits in their own folder/namespace, as I mentioned 'f31.mycompany.com/webservicegroup1/service1.svc', 'f31.mycompany.com/webservicegroup2/service2.svc' and so on.

N.B.: This is not for a shopping cart kind of an applications, but rather for our business applications that we need HTTPS for RESTful data transfer due to mild security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need separate SSL certificate for each web service? All services
>   run on the same domain

No, what you have to ensure is that your *domain* and hosts (*name* in certificate and *subject alternative name*) match whatever domain/s, host/s your service is using.

Typically standard certs have:

- www.mydomain.com as the `name`
- mydomain.com as the `subject alternative name`

or vice versa

Which translates to being able to use SSL/HTTPS on *both* www and "naked domains" (the one without "www").

<strike>In your case, you'll probably need to work with your provider so you can take advantage of this because you'll be using `f31` as one of your "hosts" - which will likely (automatically) translate to being able to use:</strike>

Actually, here's a guide to specify SAN(s) in your CSR:
[How to Request a Certificate With a Custom Subject Alternative Name](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff625722(v=ws.10).aspx)

These days, even if you're not using for "shopping", [ensure your cert uses "modern" crytpo algorithms (not SHA-1 or older)](https://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.com/2014/09/gradually-sunsetting-sha-1.html) - unsure if there are still providers out there that do, so just fyi...

Hth.

Comment: Actually, if you want your cert to be valid for both `mydomain.com` and `www.mydomain.com`, both will need to be in SANs, not just `mydomain.com`. In addition, it's not really about "domains", only about hosts (in this case, both `mydomain.com` and `www.mydomain.com` would be potential hosts).

Comment: @Bruno - AFAIK,  `subject` and `subject alternative name` - the former is typically the only thing asked when purchasing a cert, the latter is "automatic" (though not true for all providers/types of certs)....

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The subject is a Distinguished Name (DN), with multiple RDNs ("Common Name" being one of those, and it's used as the host name when there's not Subject Alternative Name). Subject Alternative Name is an optional extension that can have multiple values. If there are any DNS SAN entries, then the CN in the Subject DN is ignored. If you want the cert to be valid with and without `www.`, both values need to be in SANs. Often CAs will issue a cert with both the SANs (with and without `www.`) automatically, when you ask for either host name (but it depends on the CA).

Comment: @Bruno - Thank you for the detailed explanation - my understanding is not as detailed/in-depth as yours!